# JavaScript - Obtener únicamente la fecha

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una app en la que necesito obtener la fecha actual en JavaScript (sin la hora): lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
const to_day = new Date();
const day = to_day.getDate();
const month = to_day.getMonth()+1;
const year =  to_day.getFullYear();
const actual_date = String(day+'/'+month+'/'+year);
const new_date = new Date(actual_date);
```

Sin embargo no obtengo el resultado que deseo, por el contrario me imprime lo siguiente:

```
2021-01-09T05:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que requieres puedes hacer uso de la funcion `toLocaleDateString()`

[representación-de-fechas](https://lenguajejs.com/javascript/fechas/date-fechas-nativas/#representaci%C3%B3n-de-fechas)

si no te sirve así puedes recurrir a crear tu propia función y hacer que retorne el formato como lo deseas.

[Ejemplos de fechas con formatos distintos](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/javascript/javascript-format-date/)

También puede recurrir a usar paquetes como lo son: Moment.js con Node.js o dateformat con Node.js

Te dejo 2 ejemplos como yo sugiero que puedes hacerlos:

```js
const f = new Date();
//Devuelve formato sólo de fecha pero en el formato regional actual ejemplo: 24/8/2019
console.log(f.toLocaleDateString());

/**
 * Si no le convence, puede recurrir a hacer el ajuste manual
 **/
const formatDate = (d) => {
  return d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear()
}
console.log(formatDate(f));
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [Date.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Por ejemplo:

```js
const today = new Date()
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString()) // de acuerdo a tu idioma local
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("es-CO")) // formato fecha en Colombia, por ejemplo 9/1/2021
```

Si mas adelante requieres algo mas complejo, lo ideal es que utilices una libreria, por ejemplo https://day.js.org/

Actualmente no es tan recomendable seguir usando `Moment.js` sino que en la mayor parte de los casos es preferible otras alternativas, por las razones que los mismos desarrolladores de la libreria expresan en su documentacion https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0):

Creo que erraste y pusiste `const day = to_day.getDate()`, pero debería ser `getDay()`.

Acabo de probar esto y debería de funcionar. Lo que sucede es que al hacer `new Date(actual_date)`, te devuelve el objeto Date para esa fecha.

```
const date = new Date();
const day = date.getDay();
const month = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();
const fullYear = day+"-"+month+"-"+year; 
console.log(fullYear); //3-8-2021
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias pero en realidad el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: debes tener presente que los meses se tratan de 0 a 11, siendo 0 el mes de enero, entonces lo que tienes debes ajustarlo para que al armar la fecha el mes sea el correcto sumandole 1 dígito.